# Прилично и неприлично - этимология

Tags: этимология

Задумалась над словом "приличие". При-личие. То есть, получается, при лице.
Интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова. При чьем лице и почему это хорошо, а если не при лице, то плохо?
Или тут речь о Лике Божием?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Схема образования слова: лицо – приличие, но лицо - слово многозначное, и от правильного выбора его значения  зависит смысл образованного существительного.

Можно говорить о предмете, который нам к лицу, или в переносном смысле "не надо ударять в грязь лицом".

Но думаю, что здесь лицо здесь употреблено не в этом значении, а в значении "член коллектива", так как приличие – это норма поведения человека в обществе.

Answer (score 1):

Тут как раз все очень просто. Естественно, никакого Лика Божия здесь нет. Разве вы не слышали выражение "это тебе (ему, вам, им и т.п.) **не к лицу**? Это то же самое, что неприлично. Это платье к лицу (почти в прямом смысле), а этот поступок не к лицу (очень простая метафора).

Answer (score 1):

ликъ -> приликъ (схожесть лицом) -> приличный (старое значение: похожий) -> соответственный, уместный, подобающий (совр. значение)

(по этимологическому словарю Крылова; видимо,`форма "лицо" непосредственно не участвовала в образовании слова: приставка добавилась ещё к "лику")